# can some help me work this out

Tags: php, javascript, gd

Here is my site. I'm trying to make its own testing URL for the moment:

http://boats.instantonlinesuccess.co.uk/boat-names.html

If you look at it you can see what I am trying to do.  I'm trying to link the JavaScript to my PHP, so the writing appears with the effects / effect colours / colours.  It's all generated via a PHP script which I'm trying to write.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php header("Content-type: image/png");
    $string = $_GET['text'];
    $currentFont =$_GET['font'];
    $currentTextColour = $_GET['colour'];
    $currentEffect = $_GET['effect'];
    $currentEffectColour = $_GET['effectcolour'];
    $im = imagecreatefrompng("images/test.png");
    $px = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($string)) / 2;
    //if you exactly know the RGB color indexes//
    $rgb = imagecolorexact($im, 0, 0, 0);
    //or keep the rgb color by position so at top 0 left 0 
    $rgb = imagecolorat($im, 0, 0);
    imagecolortransparent($im, $rgb);
    imagestring($im, 64, $px, 16, $string, $currentTextColour);
    imagepng($im); imagedestroy($im); 
?>
```

If you need the JavaScript, then let me know.

Comment: Could you please make your title descriptive?

Comment: And please use proper linebreaks in your codeblock. You don't have to pay per line.

Comment: You could try changing your first line to this to debug the issue: That was true header('Content-Type: text/plain');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try changing your first line to this to debug the issue:

`header('Content-Type: text/plain');`